# Alchemy getAssetTransfers function doesn't return all transactions

Tags: transactions, blocks, alchemy, alchemy-sdk

I am using alchemy and axios to get all the transaction history for an address

Here is the code:

```
var categoryList = [];
categoryList.push("external");
categoryList.push("internal");
categoryList.push("erc20");
categoryList.push("erc721");
categoryList.push("erc1155");
console.log(categoryList);
let data = JSON.stringify({
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "id": 0,
    "method": "alchemy_getAssetTransfers",
    "params": [
      {
        "fromBlock": "0x0",
        "fromAddress": "0x4868F1B29e3bEF7e65AaE55dDe59Fb9963220C00",
        "category": categoryList
      }
    ]
  });
  
    var requestOptions = {
      method: 'post',
      headers: { 'Content-Type': 'application/json' },
      data: data,
    };
  
    const apiKey = "xxxx"
    const baseURL = `https://eth-mainnet.g.alchemy.com/v2/${apiKey}`;
    const axiosURL = `${baseURL}`;
  
    axios(axiosURL, requestOptions)
      .then(response => console.log(JSON.stringify(response.data, null, 2)))
      .catch(error => console.log(error));
```

The code returned me only one transfer transaction:

```
{


"jsonrpc": "2.0",
  "id": 0,
  "result": {
    "transfers": [
      {
        "blockNum": "0x1092a5e",
        "uniqueId": "0xcf619b3c589a469dc92aa2a421a032a37507005c0d235407b8e2302faae4be39:external",
        "hash": "0xcf619b3c589a469dc92aa2a421a032a37507005c0d235407b8e2302faae4be39",
        "from": "0x4868f1b29e3bef7e65aae55dde59fb9963220c00",
        "to": "0xef1c6e67703c7bd7107eed8303fbe6ec2554bf6b",
        "value": 0.002,
        "erc721TokenId": null,
        "erc1155Metadata": null,
        "tokenId": null,
        "asset": "ETH",
        "category": "external",
        "rawContract": {
          "value": "0x71afd498d0000",
          "address": null,
          "decimal": "0x12"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

However there are more too for this address: https://etherscan.io/address/0x4868f1b29e3bef7e65aae55dde59fb9963220c00

What is the reason?